# Why would my server make a proxy request to the same put function from two different pages and only work on one?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, redux

I am getting a proxy error from a PUT action only when its called from a certain page. When I call it from a different page, it works fine.

My code is that doesn't work is:

```
  const startedWorkout = () => {
    if (workout?.exercises && selectedWorkout) {
      if (selectedWorkout.started && selectedWorkout.completed) {
        // restarts workout session
        dispatch(toggleWorkoutIncomplete(selectedWorkout));
      }
      dispatch(startWorkout(selectedWorkout));
      dispatch(startExercise(selectedWorkout, workout.exercises));
    }
  };
```

When my frontend's URL is `http://localhost:8101/workout-started/WKsp5Odze1WuAGm6txWx`

All 3 of those functions get the same error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /workout/WKsp5Odze1WuAGm6txWx from localhost:8101 to https://us-central1-traineraid-283616.cloudfunctions.net/api.
[react-scripts] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

This is the request for each of the function calls:

```
axios.put(`workout/${workoutId}`, newValues)
```

I call the exact same functions that use the PUT request above from a different URL: `http://localhost:8101/workouts/list`
and it works fine.

I have never seen an error so specific and I have no idea where to start looking for a backend call that doesn't work on specific frontend URLs.

Let me know if i am missing something obvious. I tried to cut down on the code because it would be a lot of stuff to have to copy here but I can post here at any request for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. It turned out that I was navigating to the next page before the functions could load.

I removed the href from the button and changed the code from the onclick function to:

```
  const startedWorkout = () => {
    if (workout?.exercises && selectedWorkout) {
      if (selectedWorkout.started && selectedWorkout.completed) {
        // restarts workout session
        dispatch(toggleWorkoutIncomplete(selectedWorkout));
      }
      dispatch(startWorkout(selectedWorkout));
      dispatch(startExercise(selectedWorkout, workout.exercises));
      props.history.push(`/workout-started/${workout?.id}`)
    }
  };
```